# Не скачивается файл через href html

Tags: html, download, href

Я сделал сайт с кнопками скачивания, 2 из них работают хорошо, а третья не хочет скачивать файл, хотя если перейти по ссылке напрямую - все работает, через target="_blank" пробовал, не помогает, вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <body>

      <style>

         p {

         color: green;

         }

      </style>

      <p>Download test

      <p>

         <!-- GFG is the name of the 

            file to be downloaded-->

         <!-- In order to run the code, 

            the location of the file 

            "dnn.zip" needs to 

            be changed to your local directory,

            both the HTML and downloadable file 

            needs to be present in the same directory -->

         <p><a href="https://upnow-prod.ff45e40d1a1c8f7e7de4e976d0c9e555.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/vRxHCBLc32cTsqYbK1xfhOwuYSE3/a54eca7f-c137-47ef-a23d-20419f704b76?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=cdd12e35bbd220303957dc5603a4cc8e%2F20231112%2Fauto%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231112T075425Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Signature=8347a651de410f3cbf185127a148e1dacc1b9d2fa26b725176951a988d6ef8c4&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22dnn.zip%22" download="dnn"></p>

         <button type="button">Download</button>

         </a>
              <p><a href="dnn.zip" download="dnn"></p>

         <button type="button">Download from localhost</button>

         </a>
              <p><a href="http://file-st14.karelia.ru/v7qvg8/20771d504f34a5abb271f74af6b4c3aa/dd96ae5bae7f1e7d255acfecfca9ca1d/dnn.zip?force" target="_blank" ></p>

         <button type="button">Download Mirror</button>

         </a>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<p><a ...></p>` — вы закрыли тег p и значит автоматически закрыли все теги внутри него, в том числе и ссылку

Comment: И вообще вкладывать кнопки внутрь ссылок запрещено, так что вы в целом чушь написали

Comment: Все остальные файлы скаичваются, даже с тегом <p>

Comment: в третьей ссылке нет атрибута download

Comment: С атрибутом download тоже не работает, я убрал, т.к. скачивалось только через ссылку напрямую